# MacOS Firewall: Program grayed out, can't be added to Firewall Options

Tags: macos, security, python, firewall, monterey

In MacOS Monterey (12.0.1), I am running Python 2.7 from an Anaconda virtual environment.
Each time I run the Python script, I am asked if I want to accept incoming network connections:

[image]

I have tried multiple times to "Deny" or "Allow" this (which requires me to enter the username & password of an administrator user). However, each time I run the script I am presented with the same question.

When I go to ***System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall > Firewall Options*** and press **+** to add an application manually, I am unable to select Python 2.7 in the file picker (it's grayed out, as can be seen in the screenshot below):

[image]

According to ***Get Info***, my user has Read & Write privileges for this file, which also seems to be true in Terminal for the file and the directory it's in:

```
-rwxrwxr-x@  1  my_user  staff   8464 Oct 30 12:21 python2.7
drwxr-xr-x@  81 my_user  staff   2592 Nov 19 10:10 bin
```

How can I stop this annoying pop-up from reappearing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try controlling the firewall through the Terminal interface of the Application Firewall, [`socketfilterfw`](https://www.manpagez.com/man/8/socketfilterfw/).

#### Step-by-step

`socketfilterfw` is located under `/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall`, so first go there in Terminal:

```
cd /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall
```

Then you can list existing rules with:

```
./socketfilterfw --listapps
```

You can add an application with the following command:

```
sudo ./socketfilterfw --add <full path to application executable>
```

Terminal should print `Incoming connection to the application is permitted` when successful.

#### Example: allowing `python` through in an Anaconda install

It seems you have installed `python` through Anaconda and are trying to let it through the firewall.
In this example I go through all the steps in Terminal.
I assume that you're working in the `base` environment, if not, you need to change that name in the first steps.

```
conda activate base
python_loc=$(which python)
cd /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall
sudo ./socketfilterfw --add $python_loc
sudo ./socketfilterfw --listapps
```

The last step should show the freshly added `python` application in the list:

```
ALF: total number of apps = 8 

...

8 :  /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3.9 
     ( Allow incoming connections )
```

Note that `python` is often a symlink to another binary (e.g. `python3.9` or `python2.7`). During the creation it's fine to refer to the symlink, but when you want to remove the rule again (with `./socketfilterfw --remove`) you need to provide the actual path that is listed by `socketfilterfw` (`/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3.9` in this case), not the symlink.

Comment: Seems like `socketfilterfw --blockapp` is used to block applications.

Comment: Yes, that's what the manual says... I don't fully understand your comment. Were you actually looking to *block* the python app, instead of letting it through?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the executable's code signature becomes invalid, and that makes it impossible to make it properly work with the Firewall Options. The system will keep asking the same dialog. That can become pretty disruptive if your process restarts very often.

Running `codesign -s - -f /opt/homebrew/opt/python3/bin/python3.9` will make your next "Allow" response to the dialog or adding to the Firewall Options to persist. You may have to remove the item from Firewall Options first.

cf. https://geoff.greer.fm/2015/04/26/os-x-code-signing-and-firewalls/