# Why can't I give bluetooth privilege to python3?

Tags: macos

[image]

It is grayed out.

[image]

But other executable/symbol link work well, as you can see from the screenshot.

I found similar question [MacOS Firewall: Program grayed out, can't be added to Firewall Options](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431362/macos-firewall-program-grayed-out-cant-be-added-to-firewall-options).

But those commands only work for firewall. And he didn't answer why the icon was grayed out.